# Compare two sets of an SQL "GROUP BY" result

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here is my table:

```
ROUTES = the route ID
STATIONS = the station ID
STOPS? = if the train stops at this station then is equal to 1 otherwise 0

-------------------------
ROUTES STATIONS  STOPS?
-------------------------
R1    S1    1
R1    S2    0
R1    S3    1
R1    S4    0
R1    S5    1
R2    S1    1
R2    S2    1
R2    S3    1
R2    S4    0
R2    S5    1
R3    S1    1
R3    S2    0
R3    S4    1
R3    S5    0
R3    S6    1
R3    S7    1
R4    S1    1
R4    S2    1
R4    S3    0
R4    S4    1
R5    S2    1
R5    S3    0
R5    S4    1
```

What I am trying to do is to find which routes pass through the same stations but don't have the same stops.

For example:
We see that

```
Route R1 passes through stations S1->S2->S3->S4->S5 
Route R2 passes through stations S1->S2->S3->S4->S5
```

but they have different stops, so the result should be:

```
R1 
R2
```

I thought to group first all the ROUTES and compare the STATIONS belonging to that group with all the others and check if they have at least one different stop.

Comment: I assume that the consecutive order must be taken into acount. But where is this order? I would assume that it makes a difference if a train(or whatever) goes from london to paris or from paris to london.

Comment: the table has an order field (i did not put it here), however you don't need to worry about the order since i want to find the routes that pass through the same stations but don't have the same stops. it does not matter in which order.

Comment: If anyone needs a sql-fiddle(i have no time anymore): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4547/2/0

Comment: good question, actually.  does the sequence matter?  in other words, what if route 1 stops at A,B,C, and route2 stops at A,C,B?  Is it a match?  or are they on a rail line so the stations are always in sequence?

Comment: @Beth, no it does not matter the sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed a TrainRoutes table with one row for each of R1, R2 etc. You could replace this with select distinct RouteID from Stops if required.

```
Select
    r1.RouteID Route1,
    r2.RouteID Route2
From
    -- cross to compare each route with each route
    dbo.TrainRoutes r1
        Cross Join
    dbo.TrainRoutes r2
        Inner Join
    dbo.Stops s1
        On r1.RouteID = s1.RouteID
        Inner Join
    dbo.Stops s2
        On r2.RouteID = s2.RouteID
Where
    r1.RouteID < r2.RouteID -- no point in comparing R1 with R2 and R2 with R1
Group By
    r1.RouteID,
    r2.RouteID
Having
     -- check each route has the same number of stations
    count(Distinct s1.stationID) = count(Distinct s2.stationID) And
    -- check each route has the same stops
    Sum(Case When s1.StationID = s2.StationID Then 1 Else 0 End) = count(Distinct s1.StationID) And
    -- check each route has different halts
    sum(Case When s1.StationID = s2.StationID And s1.Halts = s2.Halts Then 1 Else 0 End) != count(Distinct s1.StationID)
```

You can also do this without the TrainRoute table like so, but you're now cross joining two larger tables:

```
Select
    s1.RouteID Route1,
    s2.RouteID Route2
From
    dbo.Stops s1
        Cross Join
    dbo.Stops s2
Where
    s1.RouteID < s2.RouteID
Group By
    s1.RouteID,
    s2.RouteID
Having
    count(Distinct s1.stationID) = count(Distinct s2.stationID) And
    Sum(Case When s1.StationID = s2.StationID Then 1 Else 0 End) = count(Distinct s1.StationID) And
    sum(Case When s1.StationID = s2.StationID And s1.Halts = s2.Halts Then 1 Else 0 End) != count(Distinct s1.StationID)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76978/8

Comment: thanks man, i tried your solution and is working perfect. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following query will return routes and stations where one of the trains does not stop, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4c5f/8.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    tblRoutes.ROUTES
   ,tblRoutesCross.ROUTES CrossingRoute
   ,tblRoutes.STATIONS
  FROM
    tblRoutes
  INNER JOIN
    tblRoutes tblRoutesCross
  ON
    tblRoutesCross.STATIONS = tblRoutes.STATIONS
  AND
    tblRoutes.ROUTES < tblRoutesCross.ROUTES
  AND
    (
       tblRoutesCross.STOPS = 0 
      OR
       tblRoutes.STOPS = 0 
    )
```

Following query will return only crossing routes:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    tblRoutes.ROUTES
   ,tblRoutesCross.ROUTES CrossingRoute
   --,tblRoutes.STATIONS
  FROM
    tblRoutes
  INNER JOIN
    tblRoutes tblRoutesCross
  ON
    tblRoutesCross.STATIONS = tblRoutes.STATIONS
  AND
    tblRoutes.ROUTES < tblRoutesCross.ROUTES
  AND
    (
       tblRoutesCross.STOPS = 0 
      OR
       tblRoutes.STOPS = 0 
    )
```

To find routes that non of the trains stop change or to and in where clause:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    tblRoutes.ROUTES
   ,tblRoutesCross.ROUTES CrossingRoute
   --,tblRoutes.STATIONS
  FROM
    tblRoutes
  INNER JOIN
    tblRoutes tblRoutesCross
  ON
    tblRoutesCross.STATIONS = tblRoutes.STATIONS
  AND
    tblRoutes.ROUTES < tblRoutesCross.ROUTES
  AND
    (
       tblRoutesCross.STOPS = 0 
      AND
       tblRoutes.STOPS = 0 
    )
```

Comment: in your crossing routes query, shouldn't '= 0 
      OR
       tblRoutes.STOPS = 0' be = 1 
      and
       tblRoutes.STOPS = 1?

Comment: @Beth 1 is when train stops on the station, 0 - when it does not, question as far I understood was to get roots that pass through the same stations, but do not stop on them.

Comment: sorry, can't figure out what you're doing after looking at your sqlFiddle.  shouldn't the final results be R1 and R2 stop at the same stations but have different stops along the way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry of my code but I'm at work , i will format later, but it's what you need in steps
Hope it helps

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (r NVARCHAR(3), s NVARCHAR(3), st BIT)
DECLARE @temp TABLE (r NVARCHAR(3), s NVARCHAR(100), st NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @table
        ( [r], [s], [st] )
VALUES  ('R1','S1',1 ),
        ('R1','S2',0),
        ('R1','S3',1),
        ('R1','S4',0),
        ('R1','S5',1),
        ('R2','S1',1),
        ('R2','S2',1),
        ('R2','S3',1),
        ('R2','S4',0),
        ('R2','S5',1),
        ('R3','S1',1),
        ('R3','S2',0),
        ('R3','S4',1),
        ('R3','S5',0),
        ('R3','S6',1),
        ('R3','S7',1),
        ('R4','S1',1),
        ('R4','S2',1),
        ('R4','S3',0),
        ('R4','S4',1),
        ('R5','S2',1),
        ('R5','S3',0),
        ('R5','S4',1)

SELECT * FROM @table

INSERT INTO @temp
        ( [r], [s], [st] )

SELECT DISTINCT r ,(
Select s + ',' AS 'data()' 
            From @table R2
            WHERE R2.[r] = [R].r
            ORDER BY [r]
            For XML PATH ('') ) [Routs]
            , (
Select CAST([st]AS NVARCHAR(2)) + ',' AS 'data()' 
            From @table R2
            WHERE R2.[r] = [R].r
            ORDER BY [r]
            For XML PATH ('') ) [Stops]
    FROM @table R

SELECT * FROM @temp

SELECT * FROM @temp WHERE [s] IN (SELECT [s] FROM @temp GROUP BY s HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )

SELECT T.* FROM @temp T
INNER JOIN (
SELECT [s], [st] FROM @temp WHERE [r] IN (
 SELECT [r] FROM @temp WHERE [s] IN 
    ( SELECT [s] FROM @temp GROUP BY s HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) )
    GROUP BY [s], [st] HAVING COUNT (*) = 1 ) X ON T.[s] = X.[s] AND T.[st] = X.[st]
```

Answer (score 0):

The real challenge here is finding routes that go through the same stations.  The idea is to compare two routes, compa and compb, by doing a self join on the table.  The comparison, of course, looks at all pairs.

Now, if we aggregate some information about the route, we can determine if they have the same stations:

- Do the join by station, so only matches are counted
- Count the number of stations on compA and on compB
- Count the number on both

The first is a condition of the join, the second is handled using window function to do the count before the join, and the third is the result of a join.

Two routes go through the same station when all these counts are the same.

Easy enough.  Now we just have to add in where there is some station that has a stop on one route but not the other.

The following query incorporates this logic:

```
select compa_Route, compb_Route
from (select compa.route as compa_route, compb.route as compb_Route,
             MAX(compa.numstations) as compa_NumStations,
             MAX(compb.NumStations) as compb_NumStations,
             SUM(case when compa.stop <> compb.stop then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentStops,
             COUNT(*) as both_NumStations
      from (select t.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by route) as numstations
            from t
           ) routea join
           (select t.*, COUNT(*) over (partition by route) as numstations
            from t
           ) routeb
           on routea.station = routeb.station and
              routea.route < routeb.route
      group by compa.route, compb.route
     ) ab
where compa_NumStations = compb_NumStations and
      compa_NumStations = both_NumStations and
      DifferentStops > 0
```

Do note that this assumes that stations are not repeated on a route.  If stations can be repeated, then the problem becomes a bit harder.

Comment: shouldn't it be compB_NumStations = both_NumStations?

Comment: @Beth . . . That condition is redundant.  If you have "a = b" and "a = c", then it follows that "a = c".  In fact, any two of these are sufficient for the equality condition.  (That said, it might be good practice to put all three conditions in for clarity's sake.)

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2005+ use recursive CTE(common table expression) for finding all stations and sum the train stops that to compare them

```
;WITH cte (id, r, s, st, max_level) AS
 (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.r ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as id,
         t.r, t.s, t.st,
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t.r) AS max_level
  FROM dbo.test11 t
  ), cte2 (id, r, s, st, max_level) AS
 (
  SELECT id, r, s, st, max_level
  FROM cte
  WHERE id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.r, CAST(ISNULL(ct.s, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(c.s, '') AS nvarchar(100)) AS s,
         ct.st + c.st, c.max_level
  FROM cte c JOIN cte2 ct ON c.id = ct.id + 1 AND c.r = ct.r
)
SELECT c.r, c.s, c.st
FROM cte2 c JOIN cte2 ct ON c.s = ct.s AND c.r <> ct.r AND c.st <> ct.st
WHERE c.id = c.max_level AND ct.id = ct.max_level
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2305/1/0)

Answer (score -1):

Just search for relational division without remainder or exact relational division.